# Call layout within a layout using RICH PYTHON , when user give a keyboard input

Tags: python-3.x, rich

I have a layout( live display), which showing some database information, . My requirement is If user provides an input from keyboard  on layout one, then a new layout will be called, which holds different set of rich renderables.

I didnt find any information for the same in rich document portal.

Any hint/suggestion on how to proceed would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich doesn't support this out of the box. For keyboard handling, have a look at [Textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual)

Comment: I am trying to install textual on RHEL 8 .6 , but seems the package is not available.

[root@prim-edb ~]# /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install textual
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `__main__.py install --user` instead.
Collecting textual
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement textual (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for textual
[root@prim-edb ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)